# Unable to reload Maven project: Cannot reconnect. java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

i got a new Mac Book and installed IntellJ, as soon as I try to import (new Project from existing source) a maven project i get the error "Unable to reload Maven project". To make it simpler, i just created a new simple maven project via start.spring.io to make sure I dont have any fancy dependencies.

I also tried to run mvn install via terminal. This was working out!

IntelliJ Log:

```
2020-06-03 18:34:17,299 [  20303]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=de.plushnikov.intellij.plugin.lombokconfig.ConfigDiscovery) 
2020-06-03 18:34:33,659 [  36663]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.rmi.NotBoundException: _DEAD_HAND_ 
2020-06-03 18:34:33,659 [  36663]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:227) 
2020-06-03 18:34:33,659 [  36663]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:93) 
2020-06-03 18:34:33,659 [  36663]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer36.main(RemoteMavenServer36.java:23) 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,012 [  37016]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to start due to java.io.EOFException 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,014 [  37018]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:445)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:385)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.access$300(MavenProjectReader.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:439)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:415)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.processRepositoryParent(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.process(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.resolveInheritance(MavenProjectReader.java:442)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.access$300(MavenProjectReader.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:439)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:415)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.processRepositoryParent(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.process(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.resolveInheritance(MavenProjectReader.java:442)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:684)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doUpdate(MavenProjectsTree.java:544)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doAdd(MavenProjectsTree.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.update(MavenProjectsTree.java:451)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.updateAll(MavenProjectsTree.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$1.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:488)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.lambda$applyProfiles$8(MavenServerManager.java:445)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:343)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:116)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.lambda$acquire$2(RemoteProcessSupport.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:207)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:251)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:170)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer$1.createSocket(RemoteServer.java:121)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
    ... 49 more
2020-06-03 18:34:34,017 [  37021]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2  Build #IU-201.7846.76 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,017 [  37021]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - JDK: 11.0.7; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,017 [  37021]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - OS: Mac OS X 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,017 [  37021]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Last Action:  
2020-06-03 18:34:34,102 [  37106]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'System Messages' is already registered in whitelist 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,102 [  37106]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'Project generator' is already registered in whitelist 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,102 [  37106]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'Heap Dump Analysis' is already registered in whitelist 
2020-06-03 18:34:34,102 [  37106]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'Low Memory' is already registered in whitelist 
2020-06-03 18:34:54,284 [  57288]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.rmi.NotBoundException: _DEAD_HAND_ 
2020-06-03 18:34:54,286 [  57290]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:227) 
2020-06-03 18:34:54,286 [  57290]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:93) 
2020-06-03 18:34:54,286 [  57290]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer36.main(RemoteMavenServer36.java:23) 
2020-06-03 18:34:54,640 [  57644]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to start due to java.io.EOFException 
2020-06-03 18:35:14,895 [  77899]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.rmi.NotBoundException: _DEAD_HAND_ 
2020-06-03 18:35:14,895 [  77899]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:227) 
2020-06-03 18:35:14,895 [  77899]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:93) 
2020-06-03 18:35:14,895 [  77899]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer36.main(RemoteMavenServer36.java:23) 
2020-06-03 18:35:15,251 [  78255]   WARN - ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to start due to java.io.EOFException 
2020-06-03 18:35:15,251 [  78255]  ERROR -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.applyProfiles(MavenServerManager.java:445)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.applyProfiles(MavenProjectReader.java:385)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.access$300(MavenProjectReader.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:439)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:415)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.processRepositoryParent(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.process(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.resolveInheritance(MavenProjectReader.java:442)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.access$300(MavenProjectReader.java:37)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:439)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader$1.doProcessParent(MavenProjectReader.java:415)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.processRepositoryParent(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.process(MavenParentProjectFileProcessor.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.resolveInheritance(MavenProjectReader.java:442)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.doReadProjectModel(MavenProjectReader.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectReader.readProject(MavenProjectReader.java:53)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProject.read(MavenProject.java:684)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doUpdate(MavenProjectsTree.java:544)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.doAdd(MavenProjectsTree.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.update(MavenProjectsTree.java:451)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsTree.updateAll(MavenProjectsTree.java:422)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.perform(MavenProjectsProcessorReadingTask.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.doProcessPendingTasks(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor.access$000(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsProcessor$1.run(MavenProjectsProcessor.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.utils.MavenUtil.lambda$runInBackground$5(MavenUtil.java:488)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:20)
    at com.intellij.util.RunnableCallable.call(RunnableCallable.java:11)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.call(ApplicationImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.lambda$applyProfiles$8(MavenServerManager.java:445)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:300)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:343)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:116)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.lambda$acquire$2(RemoteProcessSupport.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:207)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:251)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:170)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:272)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:239)
    ... 48 more
2020-06-03 18:35:15,253 [  78257]   WARN -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.createIndex(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.createContext(MavenIndex.java:383)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.access$300(MavenIndex.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex$IndexData.<init>(MavenIndex.java:674)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.doOpen(MavenIndex.java:209)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.open(MavenIndex.java:176)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.<init>(MavenIndex.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.load(MavenIndices.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.<init>(MavenIndices.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.ensureInitialized(MavenIndicesManager.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.getIndicesObject(MavenIndicesManager.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.createIndexForLocalRepo(MavenIndicesManager.java:174)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenProjectIndicesManager$3.run(MavenProjectIndicesManager.java:108)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:333)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:323)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.lambda$flush$1(MergingUpdateQueue.java:273)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:287)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:242)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:232)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:367)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:220)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:210)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:190)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$3.create(MavenServerManager.java:427)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$3.create(MavenServerManager.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getRemoteId(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:142)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.lambda$createIndex$0(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:343)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:116)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.lambda$acquire$2(RemoteProcessSupport.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:207)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:251)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:170)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:231)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer$1.createSocket(RemoteServer.java:121)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
```

I know this issue was posted several times, but i already tried all the suggested things.

I made sure that my hosts file only contains 127.0.0.1 localhost. Also checked via

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##

127.0.0.1 localhost
# 255.255.255.255   broadcasthost
# ::1             localhost
```

also checked via

```
ping localhost
```

and cache refresh that localhost really gets converted into 127.0.0.1

furthermore i updated maven to version 3.6.3 and and JDK to 1.8.0_251. I ran *mvn install* via terminal exactly with these versions of maven and JDK and it worked out pretty fine.

I also checked the firewall, i could not see any blocked call (anyways on terminal it was working).

some more configs:
maven version
[image: maven version]

maven jdk importer
[image: maven jdk importer]

java versions
[image: java version]

intelliJ version
[image: intellJ version]
Here i also changed the version from 11.0.7 to 1.8.0_251 (via Choose Runtime Plugin) with same result.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You can find the whole log here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtxZPsMq8pdpgRcHOmbzc7J3rYXb?e=ttLRWq

**Has someone still an idea what else i can do?**

Many thanks in advance!
best D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESET network protection is known to block `localhost` connections which is causing RMI to fail with this error:

```
ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - java.rmi.NotBoundException: _DEAD_HAND_
ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:227)
ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:93)
ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer36.main(RemoteMavenServer36.java:23)
ution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to start due to java.io.EOFException
```

Disable ESET or adjust the netwrok protection rules. Contact ESET support for more details or the configuration changes you need to make to allow `localhost` connections to work.

Comment: Hi,
I think your right. Googled a bit and found exactly this issue for my used ESET version 6.8.400.0. Thanks a lot! You can fix it via ESET rule:

https://forum.eset.com/topic/22080-mac-firewall-issue-after-update-to-684000/